# Node.js Inter-process communication Faulters

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipc, child-process

Given the following parent-process code:

```
//SSO
this.sso = fork('./app/utils/SSOproxy.js', [], {
  stdio: [0, 1, 2, 'ipc']
});
console.log(process);
console.log(this.sso);

//__handshake
this.sso.send({
  opcode: 'ACK',
  params: [],
  ref: null
});
console.log('STEP_1');
process.prependOnceListener('message', ((msg) => {
  if (msg.status) {
    if ((msg.opcode === 'ACK') && (msg.params[0] === 'ok')) {
      console.log('STEP_3');
    }
  }
}));

//__e.o.handshake
```

And child-process (SSOproxy.js) code:

```
process.on('message', ((msg) => {
  switch (msg.opcode) {
    //handshake
    case 'ACK':
      process.send({
        opcode: 'ACK',
        params: ['ok'],
        ref: null
      });
      console.log('STEP_2');
      break;
      //Other paths...
  }
));
```

In the log observed - STEP_1 is followed by STEP_2 but I never see STEP_3 because I can't for-the-life of me figure out how to get duplex communication for child/parent. How to achieve the same?

Comment: Can no one answer this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `prependOnceListener` you have a condition for `msg.status` but I don't see this anywhere in your `SSOproxy.js` code.

This means your if will never evaluate `true`

Can you try adding a `status` to your message:

```
process.send({
    opcode:'ACK',
    params:['ok'],
    ref: null,
    status: 'test1234'
});
```